# How to get consistency using Camera to follow path Offest?

Tags: bezier-curves, camera, constraints, path

This is not the first time I am experiencing this issue on my workflow, usually I just deal with it rearranging stuff around, but this time I would like to find a better way.
I use Camera to follow path (Bezier curve) a lot for my animations: I create the curve, and animate using the Offset value in the follow path constrain (generally I do not use the evaluation time on the curve itself setting, as here you also have to decide the duration time beforehand, doubling the problem that I now explain).
The shot then is nicely animated, etc. But now you decide to add a variation in the curve path for some reason: lets say you need to extrude the end to make the curve slight longer, or maybe just bend a point slightly differently to improve the shot. And here comes the problem: now the whole animation is off! Even if the part being edited comes at the end of the curve, also the beginning of the animation gets dislodged (as the offset of the camera gets recalculated).
How do you deal with this? How do you edit the camera curve only in the section needed without interfering with the whole set up?
I hope I was clear enough explaining.

Thanks! And cheers

Comment: You could instead create a plane, give it a Curve modifier with your curve as Curve Object, parent the camera to 3 vertices of your plane so that it follows the plane, it also has its limitations though, for example if you extrude the first vertex of your curve it will also move the plane...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But modifying the curve would also change the offset of the plane, and so of the camera, since it's parented. Not sure I understood correctly your method tho.

Comment: Here is a test: https://blend-exchange.com/b/WGay95Ob

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see, it works. Out of curiosity: why you parent to 3 vertex only ? (I would like to solve my question with your answer, but can't find the way)

Comment: If you parent to only one vertex the camera won't change its orientation but you may not need that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead create a plane, give it a *Curve* modifier with your curve as *Curve Object*, parent the camera to 3 vertices of your plane (select the camera, shift select the plane, switch to *Edit* mode, select 3 vertices and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>). Now move the plane on the correct axis so that it follows the plane. If you want the camera to stay as much vertical as possible, select the curve and in the *Data panel > Shape > Twist Method* > choose *Z-Up*. It also has its limitations though, for example if you extrude the first vertex of your curve it will also move the plane:

[image]

Blend file: [image]